# Handle more than one connection at a time in c

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I am able to create a socket , binding it to connection , listening on it and receiving results but in all this i have just 1 connection .How do i handle multiple incoming connection in c?I went through the net got some stuff but couldn't get it working..

Please help.

Comment: "went through the net got some stuff"  What *stuff* did you try?  How did it fail?  Have you read one of the many tutorials out there on socket programming?  Or reviewed code from an open source project, maybe?  What have you tried?

Comment: tried creating non blocking socket but it kept on returning non-zero values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `fork`/`threads`/`some poll` or framework functions.

simple fork example from google:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void doprocessing (int sock)
{
    int n;
    char buffer[256];

    bzero(buffer,256);

    n = read(sock,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0)
    {
        perror("ERROR reading from socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
    n = write(sock,"I got your message",18);
    if (n < 0)
    {
        perror("ERROR writing to socket");
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
    socklen_t clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

    /* First call to socket() function */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        perror("ERROR opening socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* Initialize socket structure */
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = 5001;
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    /* Now bind the host address using bind() call.*/
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
                          sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
         perror("ERROR on binding");
         exit(1);
    }
    /* Now start listening for the clients, here
     * process will go in sleep mode and will wait
     * for the incoming connection
     */
    listen(sockfd,5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    while (1)
    {
        newsockfd = accept(sockfd,
                (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
        if (newsockfd < 0)
        {
            perror("ERROR on accept");
            exit(1);
        }
        /* Create child process */
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0)
        {
            perror("ERROR on fork");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            /* This is the client process */
            close(sockfd);
            doprocessing(newsockfd);
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            close(newsockfd);
        }
    } /* end of while */
}
```

Comment: I disagree with your assertion that you *need* to use fork/threads. You *can* use fork/threads but select or poll would be sufficient also.

Comment: if you clse `sockfd` you'll get an error when you're accepting other connection!

Answer (score 2):

I'll can give you a brief description of how that would work.

You need to set up a system that listens for a connection, and when there is one it pushes it into a list of open connections. After it stores the connection in the list you create another listener. Periodically prune your list based on the connection status.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which OS, so I'm going to assume Unix/Linux.

The most common method to handle multiple connections is to process each connection in a separate process via `fork()` or using threads using `pthreads` for example. The idea is that the server waits for a connection, when one is accepted a new process is created using `fork()` or a new thread is created to handle the new connection. Here is a decent [tutorial](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=unix%20network%20programming%20concurrent%20connections&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CFMQFjAC&url=http://retis.sssup.it/~lipari/courses/OS_CP/sockets.pdf&ei=Fyy0T8jjEaPg2QX-pdEX&usg=AFQjCNFUB4og10lTxwC_chfFoCp6_Vb27A&cad=rja) you might want to have a look at.

Here is a useful [pthreads tutorial](http://students.cs.byu.edu/~cs460ta/cs460/labs/pthreads.html)